# jquery challenge with slideup and etc

Tags: jquery, menu, document, slideup

I have a code like below.  It basically opens up a menu when touched and closes again when touched on it.  However, I am trying to make it close when it's touched anywhere on screen.  Also not to make other layers move on top, I use return false, if there is a etter way let me know. Actually, overall I think this code can be better so quickly, but again I am not a programmer so doing things the visual way you know :)

```
var closed = 1;
        $(".plus").on("touchstart",function(event){
                    if(closed == 1) {
                        t=$(this).parent();
                        openmenu(t,250);
                        closed = 0;
                        $(".plus").addClass("negative");
                        return false;
                    }
                    else    {
                        var handler = function(event){
                            if($(event.target).is(".toggle, .toggle *")) return;

                            $(document).off("click", handler);

                            $(".mainNav").find(".toggle").slideUp(250,easing);
                            closed = 1;
                            $(".plus").removeClass("negative");
                            return false;
                            }   
                            $(document).on("click", handler);


                }
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(':not(.plus)').click(function(){ //close the menu });
```

Comment: where should I place this you think?

Comment: I think, anywhere inside your jquery READY function